# Execução de thread - Java EE - Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

Tenho uma aplicação web usando Jboss EAP, JSF, CDI, EJB e preciso iniciar uma thread sempre que o JBoss seja iniciado.

A thread pertence ao pacote TinyRadius que implementa um servidor Radius.
Como posso invocar o método `start` sempre ao iniciar a aplicação?

Comment: Já tentou usar um ServletContextListener?

Comment: Sim, justamente isso =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há algumas formas de fazer, como usando [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), *startup servlets* (veja `load-on-startup` na [especificação](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html)), [resource adapters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/resources.htm) em ambientes *full profile*, [EJB 3.1 @Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples002.htm#GIPVI), etc.

A decisão de qual usar varia de projeto para projeto e das várias abordagens as mais comuns são estas:

- usando [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) seria exte:

```java
@WebListener
public class YourStartupApplication implements ServletContextListener {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce)  { 
         service.doSomethingOnStartup();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce)  {
         service.doSomethingOnShutdown();    
    }

}
```

- usando [EJB 3.1 @Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples002.htm#GIPVI) um exemplo seria este:

```java
@Startup
@Singleton
public class YourStartupApplication {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup()  { 
         service.doSomethingOnStartup();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown()  {
         service.doSomethingOnShutdown();    
    }

}
```